# Using Rest Template doesn't populate a property of the object sent with type Map<String,List<string>

Tags: spring, rest, jackson, resttemplate

I am using Spring REST template to consume a rest api. I am invoking a rest endpoint in order to create something and I have an Object like the following

```
Object{
String a;
int b;
Map<String,List<String> data;
}

restTemplate.exchange(endpoint, HttpMethod.POST,
                    new HttpEntity<>(object, headers), Object.class);
```

I do see that this object contain the correct values however in the end the Object is saved but data is null.

From what I've seen JsonMapper.convertToJson(object) doesn't convert the data property with type Map. Can I replace it with another converter?

Is there a problem with the mapping converters? should I create one for doing this?

Thanks

Comment: Hi maria_k! could you post a response example?